# Shopify Custom File Structure

Tags: repository, shopify, development-environment

As you may know Shopify has a rather strict file structure on their Dawn Theme. For example,on my repository the assets folder becomes very messy in no time with CSS files, Liquid files and even images or SVGs. In Shopify´s Best Practice documentation they mention the possibility of setting Custom File Structure through File Transformation, but I couldnt get any info about that.
[image]
https://shopify.dev/themes/best-practices/file-transformation#just-in-time-file-transformations

Anyone who knows about the possibilities on that? Would it be possible to organize files in more mantainable way. Would it be possible to set a *component style* organization of (HTML/CSS/JS)?

Any hints or experience on this would be very welcome.
I am starting with Shopify coming from Angular and everything looks really fuzzy in terms of mantainability.

Comment: Are you familiar with tools like webpack?

Comment: Hi davidthorand, Just the basics. I am already researching on it. If you have experience on file bundling on a Shopify theme and you want to share your approach, please, you are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could, for example, have a setup like this:

```
├── dist
├── src
│   ├── layout
│   │   ├── theme
│   │   │   ├── theme.js
│   │   │   ├── theme.liquid
│   │   │   └── theme.scss
│   └── sections
│       └── hero
│           ├── hero.js
│           ├── hero.liquid
│           └── hero.scss
...
```

The challenge would be to move all liquid files to their respective directory which is pretty easy with the [webpack copy plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/). Just make sure to [flatten](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#flatten-copy) your files on copy when needed. This would already give you this result:

```
├── dist
│   ├── layout
│   │   └── theme.liquid
│   └── sections
│       └── hero.liquid
├── src
│   ├── layout
│   │   ├── theme
│   │   │   ├── theme.js
│   │   │   ├── theme.liquid
│   │   │   └── theme.scss
│   └── sections
│       └── hero
│           ├── hero.js
│           ├── hero.liquid
│           └── hero.scss
...
```

To get the styles and scripts you need on the right pages just determine necessary bundles and define webpack entries accordingly. You could, for example, use `src/layout/theme/theme.js` as an entry for all styles and scripts you need on all pages that use the `theme` layout.

Although Shopify's Slate is deprecated for quite some time now I recommend you checking out their webpack setup: https://github.com/Shopify/slate/tree/master/packages/slate-tools/tools/webpack

You can learn many things from that :)

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, I will take a look at Slate and to the Webpack plug-in! This really helps